# db2rspgn generates TYPE = ese for workgroup server edition, is that normal?

Tags: db2, db2-10.5

I tried to run db2rspgn on a workgroup server instance and to my surprise `<instance>.TYPE = ese` in the generated response file

```
]$ db2licm -l 
Product name:                     "DB2 Workgroup Server Edition"

]$ db2rspgn -d /opt/nya/users/db2inst1/generated_responsfile/ -i   db2inst1  -t trc

]$ grep TYPE db2server.rsp
INSTALL_TYPE = CUSTOM
db2inst1.TYPE = ese
```

I also note that the response file contains:

```
COMP = ACS
```

which is also puzzling, since the reason I like to create a response file is because I would like to add support for ACS.

Does anyone have a clue why the file is generated the way it is, and am I missing something obvious when I'm generating the response file?

Comment: The tracefile contains the row `108    ||| 1697777472 InstanceData::getNodeTypeStr 20 -DATA-  , STRING = ese`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if ese is used regardless whether it is workgroup or enterprise. At least I can't find any examples where anything but ese is used.

Running:

```
db2licm -l
```

after install reveals an un licenced Enterprice Server, but after adding a workgroup license everything looks normal.